# detect last record in ADO.Recordset?

Tags: .net, ado.net, ado

If I am looping through an ADO.Recordset (with **while not recordSet.EOF**), is there a way to detect that I'm on the last record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rs.Index == (rs.RecordCount - 1)
```

Or you could just call MoveLast.

Comment: MoveLast is not what I want... I want to *detect* the last, not *make* it the last

Answer (score 3):

`

```
Private Sub cmdForw_Click()
dataControl.Recordset.MoveNext
    If dataControl.Recordset.AbsolutePosition = adPosEOF Then
        answer = MsgBox("Add new record?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "There are no more records")
        If answer = vbYes Then
            dataControl.Recordset.AddNew
            txtTEXT.SetFocus
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

'

The AbsolutePosition Property of recordset give three values: adPosBOF, adPosEOF and adPosUnknown, this last is for NO-RECORDS in our DB.

I hope this help you.